# How do I change directory of output file without writing absolute path of out put file in crontab

Tags: 18.04, bash, python, cron

I have applied the solution to my question:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902905/python-writing-to-file-works-fine-when-done-manually-but-cron-fails

but it has not resolved.

I wish to save the file at the following location :

```
/home/user/Documents/Python/output.csv
```

Path of the script:

```
/home/user/Documents/Python/script.py
```

my cronjob

```
* * * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/Documents/Python/script.py
```

It saves the data in a new file created on the following location if I give relative path:

```
/home/user/output.csv
```

and I do not want to give absolute path for the output file.

Comment: Did you try relative (to your home directory) path?

Comment: It saves to the home directory, but I wish to save the file the above mentioned location.

Comment: You haven't told us **how** your python script decides where to write its output - if it simply creates `output.csv` in its *working directory*, then the easiest way to handle that is to change the directory before running it ex. `cd /home/user/Documents/Python && /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/Documents/Python/script.py` or equivalently `cd /home/user/Documents/Python && /usr/bin/python3 script.py`

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver the crontab is saving the output in the same directory